# Scroll bar problems

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a scrollable wx.textcontrol widget that updates during the course of the program. Whenever the text is updated,the scrollbar resets to the top of the screen. I don't want that to happen, but I can't figure out how to stop it. Does any of you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep track of the line that you are on/or has been updated and call EnsureVisible on the text control.  (Also ensure you are using Append rather than Set to add new text).

Correction, (now I have access to the help files), I was getting mixed up with MakeCellVisible from Grid controls:

YourTextCtrl.ShowPositon(YourTextCtrl.GetLastPosition()) should do the job nicely.

Even better if you call `SetInsertionPointEnd()` on your text control `before` the text is inserted, (by using `WriteText`), then your problem goes away.

Comment: wouldnt `text_ctrl.SetScrollPos(wx.VERTICAL, a_really_big_number)` also work ... without having to keep track?

Comment: I tried that and the scrollbar stays in place, but the text repaints to the top.

Comment: Managed to duplicate the problem in the wxPython demo and then found a solution  and added it above.